# Show custom posts with a specific "custom TAXONOMY slug" on startpage

Tags: custom-post-types, query

I am using this code to get all the custom post types shown on the startpage:

```
    add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse57309_alter_front_page_query');
function wpse57309_alter_front_page_query( $query ){
     if( $query->is_main_query() && is_front_page() ){
         if( !$query->get('post_type') ){
             //post type is not set, the default will be an array of them:
             $query->set('post_type',array( 'news', 'events', 'tv'));



         }
     }
}
```

But now I want only custom posts with a custom taxonomy "superevent=true".

How can I build this!?

Thank you!

AD

Answer (score 0):

For taxonomy `superevent` and term `true`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse57309_alter_front_page_query');
function wpse57309_alter_front_page_query( $query ){
     if( $query->is_main_query() && is_front_page() ){
         if( !$query->get('post_type') ){
            //post type is not set, the default will be an array of them:
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'news', 'events', 'tv' ) );
            $query->set( 'superevent', 'true' );
         }
     }
}
```